# ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4)

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, matplotlib

```
import pandas as pd
import pandas_datareader.data as web
from matplotlib import style
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
!pip install https://github.com/matplotlib/mpl_finance/archive/master.zip
from mpl_finance import candlestick_ohlc
import matplotlib.dates as mdates
import datetime as dt

style.use('ggplot')
start = dt.datetime(1996,1,1)
end = dt.datetime(2020,5,8)
df = web.DataReader('TATAMOTORS.NS', 'yahoo', start, end)
df.head()

df_ohlc = df[['Open', 'Close', 'High', 'Low']]
df_ohlc.index = df_ohlc.index.map(mdates.date2num)
df_volume = df['Volume']

ax1 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (0,0), rowspan=5, colspan=1)
ax2 = plt.subplot2grid((6,1), (5,0), rowspan=1, colspan=1, sharex=ax1)
ax1.xaxis_date()
candlestick_ohlc(ax1, df_ohlc.values, width=2, colorup='g')
ax2.fill_between(df_volume.index.map(mdates.date2num), df_volume.values, 0)
plt.show()
```

after running the above code, I'm getting the following error message

**ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 5, got 4)**

How can I resolve the following error ?

Comment: Show the full traceback as properly formatted text in the question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The candlestick_ohlc function requires 5 values (t, open, high, low, close), you need to add the time values to your input for this purpose you can use :

```
>>> values = np.hstack((np.array(df_ohlc.index).reshape(-1,1), df_ohlc.values))
>>> candlestick_ohlc(ax1, values, width=2, colorup='g')
```

I suggest also that you use mplfinance instead of mpl_finance since the latter is deprecated